# Image to function with JavaScript button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'll explain it best I can. I have the buttons (Red Ones Right side) in JavaScript so when I click on each one they turn green and when I click them again they turn red. I'm trying to get the image button (Left side) to work where if I click each one it will turn the JavaScript buttons (Red Ones Right side). Meaning I can use either one to enable/disable.

Here is image:

[image: Image for buttons]

Html code:

```
 <img src="images/menuIcons/skip.gif" width="126" height="34" />
    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
      <button id="skip" class="red" onclick="controls(this.getAttribute('class'),this.id)"></button>

<img src="images/menuIcons/text.gif" width="126" height="34" />
        <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
          <button id="text" class="red" onclick="controls(this.getAttribute('class'),this.id)"></button>

<img src="images/menuIcons/message.gif" width="126" height="34" />
    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
      <button id="message" class="red" onclick="controls(this.getAttribute('class'),this.id)"></button>

<img src="images/menuIcons/game.gif" width="126" height="34" />
        <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
          <button id="game" class="red" onclick="controls(this.getAttribute('class'),this.id)"></button>
```

Javascript code:

```
    // enable / disable Buttons
function controls(className,elem) {
    if (className == "red") {
        document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute('class','green');
        // You can define your enable statements here
    } else {
        document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute('class','red');
        // You can define your disables statements here        
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem/question? You just want to be able to click a button and turn it green, then click again to turn it back to red?

Comment: @ChrisClower I believe he wants to be able to click the text next to a button to also trigger the button. So he'd have two "switches" for one "button".

Comment: I have it setup to when you click the red circle it goes green and you click it again goes back to red. That works fine.  My question is how do I make the image buttons on the left side of it function where when I click on them the red button turns green and when I click on the button again goes back red.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the function from an `onclick` on the image, too. However, I would recommend to restructure the `controls` function to take only the `id` as an argument then.

```
<img src="images/menuIcons/skip.gif" onclick="controls('skip')" width="126" height="34" />
...
<button id="skip" class="red" onclick="controls(this.id)"></button>
<!-- the other elements analogous -->
```

```
// enable / disable Buttons
function controls(elemid) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemid);
    if (elem.className == "red") {
        elem.setAttribute('class', 'green');
        // You can define your enable statements here
    } else {
        elem.setAttribute('class', 'red');
        // You can define your disables statements here        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all a bit complex. You could surround your menu with a container and use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) to add a click handler for all items. Here is a (plain javascript) [jsfiddle mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/cXRDN/) for your menu.

Some notes on your html/code:

- don't use inline styling or javascript. Inline javascript spawns a
  new interpreter on execution.
- In your html you have more than one
  element with the same `id`, that's asking for trouble. `id`'s should
  be unique.
- Maybe you should check [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it can save you work.